# How to reset the "allow pc to be discoverable on this network" prompt?

Tags: powershell, windows-command-prompt, batch

I have been advised to ask [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1686644/how-to-reset-the-allow-pc-to-be-discoverable-on-this-network-prompt) here on ServerFault.

I've searched StackExchange, StackOverflow, and Google and I'm not finding any insights on how to reset the prompt when first connecting a PC to the internet.  I've found oodles of articles here and abroad discussing "How to disable" this prompt from showing up in the first place - BUT - I'm wanting to "reset" the prompt in order to display it again as if the machine was a fresh, virgin-clean image without ever having access to the internet or network.

Otherwise - Is it correct to assume that when the user clicks "Yes" then this becomes the equivalent of running `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes` from the command line?  I am wanting to make sure I do not enable a blanket set of rules by default if performing this action from the prompt does not do the same.

PS - I do understand the risks/benefits of allowing Network Discovery, but I am in a situation where our *client wants this* enabled . . .  PowerShell alternatives to change the rules are considered but unnecessary, as I know how to turn this on via `netsh` from Command Line.  If there is a PowerShell method to reset the prompt however, I'm all eyes.

Operating System is Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the network connection profile by deleting the registry key corresponding to the connection you want to reset here:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\<GUID>`

[image: NetworkList\Profiles registry key]
**Warning: Don't remove the `Profiles` key. Just delete the key named after the GUID you want to forget.**

The next time the computer will connect to this network, you'll be ask to select if you are on a private/public network, as expected.

If you want to find which GUID corresponds to which networks, you can take a look here `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged` because you'll find the default gateway's MAC address alongside the profile GUID.
[image: Matching the profileGuid with the default gateway mac address]
**Warning: Don't remove anything inside this key.**

Comment: I attempted this w/ both of my wireless networks within my home and did not receive the prompt.  Would a reboot in between deletion of the key and reconnection of the network be required?  For what it is worth, I see it creating a new GUID for the appropriate networks, but no prompt.